# Angular : How to pass value from config to main module by following Angular best practice recommended by john papa

Tags: angularjs, url, configuration, routes

I want to set 'base url' of the service for my angular app so that i can use relative urls in my project.

I found the concept of initialising a config module that can store some basic config data and the module can later be injected into main module as a dependency.The solution is [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html)

But I also want to follow john papa's [angular best practices](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1).

Somehow I can't combine both these concepts to produce the result.

My base controller containing configs

```
angular.module('app.config', [])
  .value('app.config', {
  basePath: 'my-base-url' // Set your base path here
});
```

My main app module and controller

```
angular.module('userManage',['ngMaterial', 'ngPassword', 'app.config'])
 .controller('addUserController', addUserController);


function addUserController($scope, $http, $window){
  $scope.pattern1 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
  $scope.submitForm = function(){
    $http({
      method : 'POST',
      url : 'my-relative-url',//(basePath+'relative url')
      data : $scope.user,
    });
 };
```

}

In the tutorial the second parameter is passed as an array and value is passed as a function parameter, How to implement this in the john papa's recommended way

There are other solutions like defining a base url value as a constant etc but defining a base module to store all configurations seems clean and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value` name will cause you trouble. Stick to names that make valid JavaScript variable names.

I'd also recommend using a constant

```
angular.module('app.config', [])
  .constant('BASE_PATH', 'my-base-url');
```

and

```
angular.module('userManage',['ngMaterial', 'ngPassword', 'app.config'])
  .controller('addUserController', addUserController);


function addUserController($scope, $http, $window, BASE_PATH) {
  // now you can use BASE_PATH
```

---

To summarise, including the `app.config` module as a dependency makes its constants, values, factories, services and other *providers* available for injection.

Comment: That did the trick.But why use constant instead of value?Thanks a lot

Comment: @jayadevkv Values may be changed by other modules, constants may not. Also, constants are available within module `config` blocks which may be helpful.